# Bigquery liquibase integration issue

Tags: google-bigquery

I am running the command liquibase update --url="jdbc:bigquery://www.googleapis.com;ProjectId=impactsmart;OAuthType=3;DefaultDataset=puma_ingestion_dev;" --changeLogFile="changelog.xml"
I am using the Simba Jar file to connect with bigquery and getting the error mentioned below

Caused by: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: [Simba]BigQueryJDBCDriver Error executing query job. Message: EXEC_JOB_EXECUTION_ERR [Failed SQL: (100032) DROP TABLE impactsmart.puma_ingestion_dev.Article_Similarity_Base1;